# Is it good to learn Selenium with Ruby?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

Is it good to learn Selenium with Ruby? Will it have market demand in coming years. I already have worked in Java and C# Selenium for 1 year each. I mean learning watir webdriver.

Comment: Java API is most popular at the moment. Python comes second. You should do a survey of your local (or target) market and make a decision based on your OWN circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning anything is good.
Coming to watir , yes it is good and in demand right now and in coming years, as major industries prefer to work with ruby instead of Java. Because they consider Java high level language.

Comment: To nitpick, I would consider **Ruby** a higher-level language than Java is. And I strongly prefer Python, for readability.